# How to get Woocommerce Rest Api shipment tracking info into c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, model-view-controller, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce rest api into my asp.net mvc application using C#.
How to get shipment tracking info of orders.
My code is -

```
string url = StoreUrl + "/wp-json/wc/v1/orders/"+ orderId + "/shipment-trackings";
            var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.ContentType = "application/json";
            req.PreAuthenticate = true;
            var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

But response return 404 not found. How to solve this problem.
Plsease know me as soon as possible.
Thanks...

Comment: 404 means your code is not wrong but the url you are creating is either incorrect or does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a quick project to help integrate with WooCommerce's new shipment tracking API. Their documentation is not very clear. It is very simple to use and handles Oauth as well. Here is an example:

```
var trackingUploader = new WCTrackingUploader("yoursecret", "yourusername", 
"yoursite");
trackingUploader.SubmitTrackingInfo("trackingid", "trackinglink", "carrier", 
DateTime.Now,
"woocommerce order id");
```

You can find the repo here: https://github.com/shipbobDev/Woo-Commerce-Tracking-Upload-C-